# Trying to create a convolutional neural Autoencoder network in Keras but it keeps crashing

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to create an autoencoder with keras and my data's shape is like this:
`(62328, 1, 40, 40)`

The error:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,40,40], [3,3,40,4]

and I don't know how to fix it. I've tried changing the `data_format` to `channels_last` or `channels_first`, but still it doesn't work.

Please help

```
K.set_image_data_format('channels_last')
dense_layer = 0
layer_size = 4
conv_layer = 1
IMG_SIZE = 40

NAME = "AutoEncoder-{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
```

loading the data

```
pickle_in = open("X5.pickle","rb")
X = pickle.load(pickle_in)
pickle_in.close()
X=np.array(X)
print( X.shape)
X= X/255

pickle_in = open("y5.pickle","rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_in)
pickle_in.close()
y=np.array(y)
```

starting with the model in keras

```
model = Sequential()
#encoding
```

this is where my problem happens

```
shape=[1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE]
print (shape)
model.add(Conv2D(4, (3,3),input_shape = shape))
```

encoding / decoding the data

```
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(2, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(2, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #encoded

#decoding
model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(4, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(1,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              )

model.summary()

model.fit(X,X,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=10,
          validation_split=0.3,
          callbacks=[tensorboard])
model.save("64x3-CND.model")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your input shape is incorrect, with the `data_format` variable set to `channels_last`, the input shape of the images is expected to be (HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS_NUM).

Changing the `data_format` to be `channels_first` should fix your problem.

```
K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, tried that and got error 
This one:                               
```ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv2d_3/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,40,40], [3,3,40,4].```

Comment: Actually your first error is fixed, this is a new one, it's due to your convolutational networks reducing the dimensions of their outputs along the way. 

Try adding padding = "same" parameter to all your conv2d layers as follows : 
Conv2D(2, (3,3), padding="same")

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you it fixed the conv2d layers but now the pooling layers are reporting something else ************* ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_259/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,40,4].

Comment: Add the same padding parameter to the MaxPool layers 

padding = "same" 

If this solved your problem, kindly mark the answer as correct for others.